# Is there a shorter more concise way to hide & show div with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a dashboard with approximately 20 divs starting with "display: none;".

When the .onClick() in the sidebar will be used, it will show a specific div and keep hidden all the others.
I have used the classic solution of creating a function for each div, however, is extremely lengthy and the code looks like a mess.

Is there a better cleaner way to achieve this with Javascript?

Here is my code:

```js
function presale() {
  var x = document.getElementById("presale");
  var y = document.getElementById("claim");
  var z = document.getElementById("stake");
  if (x.style.display === "grid") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "grid";
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function claim() {
  var x = document.getElementById("presale");
  var y = document.getElementById("claim");
  var z = document.getElementById("stake");
  if (y.style.display === "grid") {
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "grid";
    z.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function stake() {
  var x = document.getElementById("presale");
  var y = document.getElementById("claim");
  var z = document.getElementById("stake");
  if (z.style.display === "grid") {
    z.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.style.display = "none";
    z.style.display = "grid";
  }
}
```

```css
*,
html {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
}

#presale,
#claim,
#stake
/* Here I have many other divs like below */

{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MOD.CSS">
  <script src="main2.js"></script>
  <title>Base Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
      <li onclick="presale()">Presale</li>
      <li onclick="claim()">Claim</li>
      <li onclick="stake()">Stake</li>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
    </ul>
    <div id="presale">
      <h1>Presale</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="claim">
      <h1>Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="stake">
      <h1>Stake</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a better way to do this without the need to create a function and repeat the same thing over and over for each div?

Comment: If you were using a front-end framework like React or Vue, you could do it using data binding.

Comment: A framework isn't the panacea for every little problem.

Comment: @Andy I don't disagree but a framework _does_ address this (and the other inevitable questions that will follow). Also...frameworks usually have a "right" way to do something. These answers will inevitably be a javascript free-for-all.

Comment: But the expense in time of learning something like React/Angular/Vue pales in comparison to understanding how to use use data attributes as I think most of these answer have demonstrated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for JS at all. You can simply use an anchor and use `#id` as hyper reference. Then you can display the element through CSS by using the `:target`-selector:

```css
*,
html {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
}

.d-none
/* Here I have many other divs like below */

{
  display: none;
}

div:target {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MOD.CSS">
  <script src="main2.js"></script>
  <title>Base Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
      <li><a href ="#presale">Presale</a></li>
      <li><a href ="#claim">Claim</a></li>
      <li><a href ="#stake">Stake</a></li>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
    </ul>
    <div id="presale" class="d-none">
      <h1>Presale</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="claim" class="d-none">
      <h1>Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="stake" class="d-none">
      <h1>Stake</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the shortest "js-solution" I've ever seen. :D 
very smart: +1

Comment: Good solution indeed ! But can you keep the possibility of unselect an element then ?

Comment: Smart and different. +1 for that, but I would not use it in production.

Comment: Is it possible to highlight the current <li> element without js too?

Comment: yes if you use `radio-buttons` and wrap the anchors in `labels` Then you can highlight the lable with the `:checked`-selector

Answer (score 7):

Here you see a vanilla Javascript solution.

`content` divs are by default hidden.

If you click an element, the corresponding `data-id` get the class `show`.

```js
window.onload = function () {

  document.querySelectorAll('#nav li').forEach((elements) => {
    elements.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
      document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach((item) => {
        // hide all
        item.classList.remove('show');
      });
      // show one
      document.getElementById(el.target.getAttribute('data-id')).classList.add('show');
    });
  });

};
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li data-id="presale">Presale</li>
  <li data-id="claim">Claim</li>
  <li data-id="stake">Stake</li>
</ul>
<div id="presale" class="content">
  <h1>Presale</h1>
</div>
<div id="claim" class="content">
  <h1>Claim</h1>
</div>
<div id="stake" class="content">
  <h1>Stake</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this using data attributes and classlist toggles should also work.

I would consider minimizing your code (and CSS) by using generic CSS selectors to hide/show the individual sections. This also makes scalability and maintainability easier for the next guy.

This has the added benefit of your styling being controlled 100% using CSS and not arbitrary inline styles set by the javascript.

Adding another section is also easy as can be:

1. Add a new section with some id (eg. `awesome-section`)
2. Add a nav entry with the attribute `data-toggle-section` with the id as the value `<li data-toggle-section="awesome-section">Awesome Section</li>`
3. Profit

You're also not restricted to using just the nav elements themselves as the event listener is bound using the `[data-toggle-section]` selector which means that basically anything can show or hide a section as long as it has that attribute with the correct value.

```js
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-toggle-section]"));
const sections = buttons.map(element => {
    return document.getElementById(element.dataset.toggleSection)
});

buttons.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        const selected = element.dataset.toggleSection;

        sections.forEach(section => {
            if(section.id === selected) {
                section.classList.toggle('shown');
            } else {
                section.classList.remove('shown');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

```css
*,
html {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
}

.option-section {
    display: none;
}

.option-section.shown {
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
        <li data-toggle-section="presale">Presale</li>
        <li data-toggle-section="claim">Claim</li>
        <li data-toggle-section="stake">Stake</li>
        <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
    </ul>
    <div id="presale" class="option-section">
        <h1>Presale</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="claim" class="option-section">
        <h1>Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="stake" class="option-section">
        <h1>Stake</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One minor improvement, use selectors to determine which to show/hide rather than `sections.forEach`

Comment: It's not a major improvement, and I'm not even sure it would be an actual improvement apart from a small amount of memory. Using the document.querySelectorAll for each event would in turn use a bit more CPU - I think it'd be more of a trade-off than an improvement.

Comment: `if (section.id === selected) { section.classList.toggle('shown'); } else { section.classList.remove('shown'); }` can be simplified to: `section.classList.toggle('shown', (section.id === selected));`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply assign the same class (*e.g.* `my_div`) to every showable `div`, then pass the `id` to your function (that will show that and hide all the others).

```js
function show_hide(id) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.my_div').forEach(my_div => {
    my_div.style.display = my_div.getAttribute('id') == id ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
.my_div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="show_hide('presale')">Presale</li>
    <li onclick="show_hide('claim')">Claim</li>
    <li onclick="show_hide('stake')">Stake</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="my_div" id="presale">
    <h1>Presale</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="my_div" id="claim">
    <h1>Claim</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="my_div" id="stake">
    <h1>Stake</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for Code Review section https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

However, you can try smth like this:

```
const elems = ["presale", "claim", "stake"];

function toggle(elem) {
    elems.map(i => {
        let el = document.getElementById(i);
        el.style.display = "none";          
    });
    let active_el = document.getElementById(elem);
    active_el.style.display = "grid";
}
```

and in html add the elem name as a param, so, replace this

```
    <li onclick="presale()">Presale</li>
    <li onclick="claim()">Claim</li>
    <li onclick="stake()">Stake</li>
```

with this

```
    <li onclick="toggle('presale')">Presale</li>
    <li onclick="toggle('claim')">Claim</li>
    <li onclick="toggle('stake')">Stake</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt. It's sensibly the same as @ztom's answer but I tryed avoiding a `foreach`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let shown = document.querySelector(".action:not(.d-none)")
  if(shown){
    shown.classList.add("d-none")
    if(e.dataset.id != shown.id){
      document.getElementById(e.dataset.id).classList.remove("d-none")
    }
  }else{
    document.getElementById(e.dataset.id).classList.remove("d-none")
  }
}))
```

```css
.action{
  display:grid;
}
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-id="presale">Presale</li>
  <li data-id="claim">Claim</li>
  <li data-id="stake">Stake</li>
</ul>
<div class="action d-none" id="presale">Presale</div>
<div class="action d-none" id="claim">Claim</div>
<div class="action d-none" id="stake">Stake</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to use the same logic on multiple elements, use classes instead of id's and your solution is shortened by default.

With `jQuery`, it's basically a 2-liner:

in CSS, create a class `.hidden` with `display:none;`
Your `div` and `li` elements should be grouped, using a class too.

Then you can simply refer to this classes and add the show/hide logic by:

```
$('h1:contains('+$(this).text()+')').parent().toggleClass("hidden"); 
$('h1:not(:contains('+$(this).text()+'))').parent().addClass("hidden");
```

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').on('click',function(){
    $('h1:contains('+$(this).text()+')').parent().toggleClass("hidden"); 
    $('h1:not(:contains('+$(this).text()+'))').parent().addClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
html {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
}

.hidden
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MOD.CSS">
  <script src="main2.js"></script>
  <title>Base Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
      <li class="toggle">Presale</li>
      <li class="toggle">Claim</li>
      <li class="toggle">Stake</li>
      <!-- Here I have other 20 options like the above -->
    </ul>
    <div class="hidden">
      <h1>Presale</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <h1>Claim</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <h1>Stake</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you attach [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to both the list items and the "panels" you can use one function to match them up, and use a CSS class to determine whether it should be active or not.

```js
// Cache the elements, the panels container, and the list element
// separately adding one event listener to the list. We're using
// event delegation for this - one listener captures all
// the events from its child elements
const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.list li, .panels .panel');
const panels = document.querySelector('.panels');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
list.addEventListener('click', handlePanel);

// When the listener is triggered
function handlePanel(e) {
  
  // Check if it's a list item
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {

    // Destructure its id from the dataset
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;

    // Remove all the active classes from the elements  
    allElements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));

    // And then add an active class to the list item,
    // and the panel where their ids match
    const selector = `[data-id="${id}"]`;
    const item = list.querySelector(`li${selector}`);
    const panel = panels.querySelector(`.panel${selector}`);
    
    item.classList.add('active');
    panel.classList.add('active');
  
  }

}
```

```css
.panel { display: none; }
.panel h1 { font-size: 1.2em; color: darkblue; }
ul { list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0; padding: 0; }
li { padding: 0.3em; border: 1px solid white; }
li:hover { background-color: thistle; cursor: pointer; }
li.active { border: 1px solid #454545; background-color: lightyellow; }
.panel.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li data-id="presale">Presale</li>
  <li data-id="claim">Claim</li>
  <li data-id="stake">Stake</li>
</ul>

<div class="panels">
  <div data-id="presale" class="panel">
    <h1>Presale</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-id="claim" class="panel">
    <h1>Claim</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-id="stake" class="panel">
    <h1>Stake</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) / [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)