# Set table (menu) to show different tables after clicking a link <a>. Is there a way to do this with only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu table that I am trying to get to switch like the site here: https://artsdistrictkitchen.com/ I think that with Pseudo-Classes I can get it to hide/activate when I click on a specific link. How would I go about doing this? Is this even possible? I have tried this looking MDN and similar functions but I can not get it to work correctly on this scale.

```
  /*MENU TABLE*/
        
        .table {
          background-color: #1A9AE3;
          padding-top: 100px;
          padding-bottom: 100px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        table {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          padding: 40px;
          font-size: 1vw;
          background-color: white;
          border: 15px black;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        
        /*Add border.*/
        
        thead {
          text-align: right;
        }
        
        td:nth-child(even) {
          text-align: left;
          padding-left: 100px;
        }
        
        td:nth-child(odd) {
          text-align: right;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .row {
          display: flex;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        table a {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: black;
        }
        
        
        /*Change color based off background*/
        
        table a:link {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        table a:visited {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        table a:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        table a:active {
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        th {
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        
        /*ABOUT TEXT*/
        
        .about {
          height: auto;
          padding-top: 5vh;
          padding-bottom: 5vh;
        }
        
        .column {
          flex: 50%;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .column h2 {
          font-size: 2vw;
          padding-left: 200px;
        }
        
        .column p {
          padding-right: 200px;
          padding-top: 88px;
        }
        
        .column img {
          width: 500px;
          padding-left: 200px;
        }
```

Comment: There are 2 different ways to do it. You can use anchors and the `:target` selector as [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72618513/14072420). Or youc an use radio-buttons and inlcude the tables within the labels and only show the table with the `:checked` selector.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest CSS only option would be the usage of radio-inputs. Then hide the radio-button itself and only show the the element that belong to the `:checked` input:

```css
/* hides the radio-button and the div's by default */
.container > input,
.container > table {
  display: none;
}

/* makes the div for the selected element visible */
.container > input:checked + label + table {
  display: block;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.container label {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.container > table {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" id="item-1" name="Menu" checked>
  <label for="item-1">Burger</label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Burger</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hamburger</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cheeseburger</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chili-Cheeseburger</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <input type="radio" id="item-2" name="Menu">
  <label for="item-2">Dessert</label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Dessert</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ice Cream</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Strawberry-Cheesecake</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pancakes</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <input type="radio" id="item-3" name="Menu">
  <label for="item-3">Beverages</label>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Beverages</td>
      <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Water</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Soda</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Beer</td>
      <td>1,00$</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: highlight label when active
`.container>input:checked+label {
            font-weight: 700;
        }`

Comment: Is there a way to make the label elements have less line spacing? Also have the td elements align to the top of each row?

Comment: all a question of css. The space is a gap created by the gap property.