# Align items to top and narrow column in radio button grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have edited radio button grid layout menu that shows a table based on what is selected. I am having trouble styling it. I am trying to get the first column to not have so much horizontal space between the items and the td cells to align with each other to the top.

After inspecting the page, I tried to set the .container height with no resolve and also the height of the table element. I also tried align-items for the table.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="table">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="radio" id="item-1" name="Menu" checked>
    <label for="item-1">Beverages & Drinks</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Beverages & Drinks</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Coca Cola Products</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Super Float</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bottle Vintage Sodas</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <input type="radio" id="item-2" name="Menu">
    <label for="item-2">Appetizers</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Appetizers</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wing Snack</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Loaded Quesadilla</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Super Sampler</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <input type="radio" id="item-3" name="Menu">
    <label for="item-3">Snacks & Sides</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Snacks & Sides</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fries</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Loaded Tater Tots</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Onion Rings</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="radio" id="item-4" name="Menu" checked>
    <label for="item-4">Burgers and Baskets</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Burgers and Baskets</a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hamburger</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cheeseburger</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chili-Cheeseburger</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="radio" id="item-5" name="Menu" checked>
    <label for="item-5">Desserts</label>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Desserts</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hamburger</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cheeseburger</td>
        <td><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</p></td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chili-Cheeseburger</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis accumsan, dolor sed consectetur tempor, felis dolor tempus velit, lacinia suscipit ipsum ipsum quis quam. Vestibulum convallis nisi a orci maximus, nec vehicula neque luctus. Cras non aliquam turpis. Aenean vehicula turpis et scelerisque blandit.</td>
        <td>$1.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

/* hides the radio-button and the div's by default */
.container > input,
.container > table {
  display: none;
}

/* makes the div for the selected element visible */
.container > input:checked + label + table {
  display: block;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 33.33%;
  margin-right: 33.33%;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 1vw;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 8px black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.container label {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  text-align: right;
}

.container > table {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  text-align: left;
}

.container > table a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
} /*Change color based off background*/

.container label:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container label:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container>input:checked+label {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, a table element is not a `display: grid` but `display: table`. It looks like you're trying to treat it like a grid when it is, by design, not meant to do so. You can use CSS to change all the different table elements display types but you would be better off either sticking to table styling or changing all table/tr/td elements to divs.

Comment: I have to use a table per the list of requirements. Using via response from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733042/set-table-menu-to-show-different-tables-after-clicking-a-link-a-is-there-a If it is possible to change this to a `display: table` what would I do to? Would I be able to style it as normal?

Comment: I don't understand why you are required to use a table, but it is the right element for your situation. What you don't want to use are grid css properties on a table display.