# Select interact to a specific html element with a button

Tags: javascript, html, bulma

I have a few buttons in the HTML file code with Bulma similar like this:

```
<a class="button" data-target="A">Section A</a>
<a class="button" data-target="B">Section B</a>
<a class="button" data-target="C">Section C</a>
```

And there are a few section like this which can interact with the buttons:

```
<div id="A" class="contentswitch">
  <article class="message">
     <div class="message-header" id="h1">
       <p>Section A-1</p>
     </div>
     <div class="message-body">
          Message 1 of section A
     </div>
     <div class="message-header">
       <p>Section A-2</p>
     </div>
     <div class="message-body">
       Message 2 of section A
     </div>
   </article>
</div>
```

As I add code like this in the JS, it can add a class called "is-hidden" to all the div ejectment which contains "contentswitch" class.

```
$("a.button").on("click", function(){
      $("div.contentswitch").addClass("is-hidden");
    });
```

What can I do if I want to remove the class ("is-hidden") from specific div element, like if I click the button of Section A, then it add "is-hidden" class to all the div element contain content switch then remove it from the div element with the id "A"?

Thank you so much

Comment: anchors (`<a>`) =/= as a button (`<button>`). An anchor redirects to another resource while a button is a trigger to fire a script/function. In your case an actual button should be used!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a shorter more concise way to hide & show div with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72617531/is-there-a-shorter-more-concise-way-to-hide-show-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-target` to connect the clicked button to the `div` you want to show. And hide the rest of them.

Also, use `button` iso `a` tag. `a` tag has a specific purpose in HTML and should be used only in combination with `href` attribute.

```js
const buttons = $('.button');
const contentSwitchDivs = $('.contentswitch');

buttons.on("click", function(){
    const btnTarget = $(this).data('target')
    const contentToShow = $(`#${btnTarget}`)
    contentSwitchDivs.not(btnTarget).hide();
    contentToShow.show();
});
```

```css
.contentswitch {
  display: none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-target="A">Section A</button>
<button class="button" data-target="B">Section B</button>
<button class="button" data-target="C">Section C</button>
                        

<div id="A" class="contentswitch">
  A contentswitch
</div>
<div id="B" class="contentswitch">
  B contentswitch
</div>
<div id="C" class="contentswitch">
  C contentswitch
</div>
```

Comment: Because I need to use the button class in a tag to work with Bulma framework, but your answer works perfectly for what I need. Thank you so much.