# Show/hide multiple spans using a single javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following pure JS code to show/hide span:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(".loginArea").hide();
$(".showLoginArea").click(function(){
    console.log('login');
    $(".loginArea").toggle();
});
    });
```

The html code works if used once, but I need to use it multiple times:

```html
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area</span>
```

I need to make something this work without writing JS code for each span class:

```html
<span class="showLoginArea1">Login</span> <span class="loginArea1">This is Login Area</span>
<span class="showLoginArea2">Login</span> <span class="loginArea2">This is Login Area</span>
<span class="showLoginArea3">Login</span> <span class="loginArea3">This is Login Area</span>
...
```

Comment: event delegation will help you here

Comment: If they are indexed properly, a simple `for` loop will do. Otherwise, add a common class.

Comment: How would a common class help me? Wouldn't they all open and close at the same time?

Comment: Use the common class to query them all, then add event listeners one by one.

Comment: Use a single class (remove all the `..1`, `..2` classes, they're confusing the issue) and use relative DOM navigation.

Comment: @freedomn-m that sounds like what I need, could you please help me further by explaining how to add relativity to my JS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72617531/is-there-a-shorter-more-concise-way-to-hide-show-div-with-javascript/72618513#72618513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your code work the same way for each element, each element needs to be built the same:

```
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area</span>
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area</span>
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area</span>
...
```

You then use *relative DOM navigation* to link between the - without changing your HTML, this gives:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".loginArea").hide();
  $(".showLoginArea").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
span { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 1</span>
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 2</span>
<span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 3</span>
```

Note that `.next()` is very brittle as it has to be the next element in the DOM - if you change your layout slightly, this will break, so wrap your show+area in a div, giving:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".loginArea").hide();
  $(".showLoginArea").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").find(".loginArea").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 1</span></div>
<div><span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 2</span></div>
<div><span class="showLoginArea">Login</span> <span class="loginArea">This is Login Area 3</span></div>
```

In the case where your two elements (the element being clicked and the element being shown) are in completely different locations (eg a tab bar and content) then you can link them using data- attributes:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".loginArea").hide();
  $(".showLoginArea").click(function() {
    var area = $(this).data("login");
    $(".loginArea").hide();
    $(`.loginArea[data-login="${area}"]`).show();
  });
});
```

```css
span { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="showLoginArea" data-login="1">Login</span> 
<span class="showLoginArea" data-login="2">Login</span> 
<span class="showLoginArea" data-login="3">Login</span> 

<hr/>

<span class="loginArea" data-login="1">This is Login Area 1</span>
<span class="loginArea" data-login="2">This is Login Area 2</span>
<span class="loginArea" data-login="3">This is Login Area 3</span>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you very much for taking the time to explain this for a newbie!

Comment: @Mr.Fontastic added a 3rd option to link